# Performance difference for $(this) vs var mythis=$(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an application using jquery and I am using $(this) at many places for various operations like hasClass, addClass, attr etc.

Should I keep this as it is or declare a variable like

```
var mythis=$(this);
```

and use **mythis** for further calls.

In which case the application performance will improve?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should keep $(this) as it is more readable. Performance wise it's very close.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvf0wge0/1/), it does not really matter. So, as @Fawzan says, keep `$(this)` for better readability.

```
var iterationMax = 100000;

var t1Start = Date.now();
for(var i=0; i<iterationMax; i++) {
  var hasClass = $('#jquery-test').hasClass("no-class");
}
var t1End = Date.now();

var t2Start = Date.now();
var jqueryRef = $('#jquery-test');
for(var i=0; i<iterationMax; i++) {
  var hasClass = jqueryRef.hasClass("no-class");
}
var t2End = Date.now();

$("#t1").html("T1 took: " + (t1End - t1Start) + " ms");
$("#t2").html("T2 took: " + (t2End - t2Start) + " ms");



<div id="jquery-test"></div>

<div id="t1"></div>
<div id="t2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `var mythis=$(this)` will slightly improve your performance.

Because `$(this)` will initialize an jquery object that binds to current scope. If you keep this object in a variable, It saves performance from that initialization

Out of questions, I think it is better to use

```
var myID = $("#id");
var myClass = $(".your_class");
...
```

For id, class, attributes object ., etc Because when use `$()`, Jquery will search and initialize jquery object from current website DOM that costs performance if It needs to scan from many dom

Answer (score 0):

var mythis=$(this);

Will be better.

By $(this) is making a function call time and again and giving the reference to this object.

In simple terms if you're summing 2 numbers, what is better ? storing the result once or,calculating time and again. Storing the result.. right?